# Updating the display_name in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to update the display_name of a user in Snowflake.

I was able to unset the current display name with the following:
ALTER USER JOHNSMITH UNSET display_name; *This was successful and now there is no display_name for the user.*

I am unable to add a new display name. I have tried the following:

ALTER USER JOHNSMITH set display_name JSmith; *SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 36 unexpected 'JSmith'.*

ALTER USER JOHNSMITH set display_name 'JSmith'; *SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 36 unexpected ''JSmith''*

The SQL error is at the name, not the set command, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

ALTER USER JOHNSMITH set display_name "JSmith"; *SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 36 unexpected "JSmith"*

A follow up question - is there any implication when updating the display_name?

Comment: There should be = between the parameter name and value: DISPLAY_NAME = <string>. Could you please try it like that?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ALTER USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#syntax) doc's

> ALTER USER [ IF EXISTS ] [  ] SET TAG <tag_name> = '<tag_value>' [ , <tag_name> = '<tag_value>' ... ]

thus:

[image]

```
alter user sim4 set display_name = 'new name';
```

[image]